# How do I make an integral symbol larger in in-line math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I have the following formula in my LaTeX code:

```
$ \mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = \int_{a}^{b} $
```

This gives me the follwing in my document

[image]

Now I tried to use `\bigint`, but that gives me too thick integral... what do I need to do to get the same thickness but with more height?

Comment: Like what happens when you use `\displaysize`? Or may be you want to use `\[\int…\]` instead of `$\int…$`?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that \displaysize, I will try thnx! I tried \\[\int..\\] but then my formula moved horizontally much more right and vertically more down?! x)

Comment: For future reference, have a look at the Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX

Comment: @KhaledHosny Shouldn't it be `\displaystyle`? However, a big integral in an inline formula will irremediably spoil the page.

Comment: @egreg: you are right of course :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

More height comes with display mode:

```
\[ \mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = \int_{a}^{b} \]
```

[image: Display mode]

Or you can only make the integral larger:

```
$ \mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = {\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} } $
```

[image: Displaystyle]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! =)

Answer (score 20):

There are a few ways to change the appearance- `\displaystyle` is one of them, and you can also use `\limits`, or even a combination:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $ \mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = \int_{a}^{b}$
    \item $\mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = \int\limits_{a}^{b} $
    \item $ \mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} $
    \item $ \mu_{x_{t}} = E(x_{t}) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{a}^{b} $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

For future reference, have a look at the [Not so short Introduction to LaTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! I will =) It's you know sometimes just easier to ask 5 second thing from someone than to read whole book. Sometimes you do find the 5 second thing right away and sometimes you don't and when you don't it usually can scale up to hours, because when you look at one thing then you need to reference another thing and then another and that takes too much time for every single character in thesis ;)